# разделить массив вывода

Tags: php, mysql

имеется запрос:

```
SELECT  users FROM category  WHERE id_cat = 10
UNION
SELECT  users FROM category  WHERE  id_cat = 20
```

формирую массив для вывода

```
  $arr_cat = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $arr_cat[] = array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "cat_name" => $row['cat_name'],
                "id_cat" => $row['id_cat'],
            );
        }
    
     return  $arr_cat;
```

Получаю вывод:

```
0   Object { .......}
id           "1"
cat_name    "book"
id_cat      "10"

1   Object { .......}
id           "2"
cat_name     "book"
id_cat       "10"

2   Object { .......}
id          "3"
cat_name    "car"
id_cat      "20"
```

---

Как сформировать массив для такого результата???:

```
book: [ {…}, {…},]
       0   Object { .......}
       id           "1"
       cat_name    "book"
       id_cat      "10"

       1   Object { .......}
       id           "2"
       cat_name     "book"
       id_cat       "10"

car: [ {…},]
       0   Object { .......}
       id          "3"
       cat_name    "car"
       id_cat      "20"
```

Comment: `$arr_cat[$row['cat_name']][] = $row;`

Comment: @InDevX, так только одна запись выводится

Comment: А как вы это используете?

Comment: @InDevX, в цикл вместо старого массива подставляю

Comment: Странно. Должно всё добавлять.. Попробуйте сделать как в ответе указали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

уберите циклы и используйте[`PDO::fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php) передав `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP`. Столбец категории сделайте первым  в списке выборки.

а-ля

```
$sql = "SELECT cat, id, name FROM users WHERE id_cat IN (10,20)";
$st= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

получите искомый массив.

Comment: $result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP); если это окончательный вывод - то не работает, выводит первую запись в которой просто все поля из таблицы перечислены

Comment: @Юрий это весь код который нужен, чтобы получить желаемое вами поведение.  Убедитесь в корректности вашего SQLзапроса,  и что имя категории, как написано, стоит первым в списке select

Comment: заработало, изначально * выбирал